# Resource pictures not include in directory

Tags: image, vb6

I am creating a vb6 application now and most of my command buttons were graphical style. Do the background images still show up even if I remove them from the app folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of what goes into .FRX, .CTX, etc. files.  Those are resource files created in a private "property bag" type format and are used to hold things like binary data, images, long strings, and so on.

But don't discard your source files, because you may need them down the road.  Treat such things as valuable parts of the program source.  They are not needed at run time though.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, i'll keep that in mind. thanks again, have a good day bro.

Answer (score 1):

As far a I know it doesn't remove the picture from the command button when you delete it from the app folder, i suggest making a copy of your image and then delete the original and see if it works in case it doesn't you have the backup image, good luck.